# Printing user string input twice in the same line in Assembly Language

Tags: string, assembly, x86, dos

I am currently studying how to print user input in Assembly Language. My goal is to print the input twice on the same line. However, what I currently did is printing them on different lines. What caused the issue here?

This is what I tried:

```
dosseg
.model small
.stack

.data
prompt1 db "Hello, what's your name?:$"
prompt2 db 13,10, "$"
strprompt db 30 dup('$')


.code
main proc
mov ax,@data
mov ds,ax

lea dx,prompt1
mov ah,09h
int 21h

mov ah,10
lea dx,strprompt
mov strprompt,30
int 21h


lea dx,prompt2
mov ah,09h
int 21h

lea dx, strprompt+2
mov ah, 09h
int 21h

lea dx,prompt2
mov ah,09h
int 21h

lea dx, strprompt+2
mov ah, 09h
int 21h

mov ax, 4c00h
int 21h

main endp
end
```

The output should look like this if you input your name:

```
namename
```

But mine is:

```
name
name
```

Comment: The user-input string normally includes the newline that resulted from the user pressing Enter.  Remove that if you don't want to output a newline before the next thing you print.

Comment: @SafdarFaisal pardon me, but which part exactly or what line/block of code should I remove?

Comment: @PeterCordes do I remove my strprompt variable or the prompt2 variable? because either removing the prompt2 variable messed up the output.

Comment: You need to remove the newline character from the input. You do not remove stuff from the code. In fact you need to write more code which removes the newline :D

Comment: @Jester thank you. But pardon me, since I am not familiar with it yet, but what kind would I have to add to my code in order for the newline to be removed?

Comment: Since the input function returns the number of bytes stored, you can use that to change the last char to a `$`. Ideally you'd also check if that was indeed a newline but a simple solution would be something like `mov bx, strprompt+1; mov byte ptr [strprompt+1+bx], '$'`

Comment: @Jester: The length used is in a byte, so you have to zero-extend the byte value to `bx` and you need to address as `[strprompt+2+bx]`

Comment: Yeah, good point about the byte. I still think it should be `+1` though.